# How to get filename of custom filetype file that was loaded into my application from windows explorer?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, deployment, file-type

In my application I have my own custom filetype. I set it up so my application opens up files of this type when they are clicked outside of my application. Now my question is: How can I get the SafeFileName of the file being opened? I know that that variable S is my filename, although I want to get just the actual files name without the location.

```
    If (Environment.GetCommandLineArgs.Length > 1) Then

      Dim s As String = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(1)

     ' Open file s

    End If
```

I know if I was using the filename it would be OpenFileDialog.SafeFileName, and that would give me  test123.txt instead of C:\Files\Test123.txt

How could I do the same in this situation.

Comment: Please say how this is different from your earlier question.

Comment: If you read my previous question, you would see that it is asking something different. Hence why I created a different thread, for a different question. I realize it is against the rules to post more than one question in the same topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what the string that is being returned looks like and if it is a valid path, if it is like your example you can use [Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.100%29) Method of the System.IO Namespace.

```
Dim s As String = "C:\Files\Test123.txt"
Dim myFile As String = Path.GetFileName(s)
```